# What are the differences between those two approaches of threading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, inheritance, architecture

I am going to implement a job based threading architecture. That means on the one hand, there is a queue where the main thread can append jobs to. On the other hand there are worker threads, dependent on the number of available CPU cores, consuming those jobs and removing them from the queue.

Now, there are two approaches to implement that in C++ coming to my mind. The first one is template based. There is a `Task` template representing one job. It holds a function, which might be a lamda and provides access to the data.

To use this, we'd have to store something in the `Work` function object, like a lambda expression. Moreover, we need to point the `Data` pointer to our data object and set `Empty` to false after that. Of course than the object must be attached to the job queue. A worker thread fetching the job will lock `Access`, and the main thread can check the lock to get free every some time to work with the result then.

```
template <class T>
class Task
{
public:
    Task()
    {
        Empty.store(true);
        Data = nullptr;
    }
    std::mutex Access;
    std::atomic<bool> Empty;
    std::function<void(T*)> Work;
    T *Data;
};
```

The second approach is inheritance based. The empty flag and mutex remain like in the first approach. But the work function is a real method which wants to get overridden. Furthermore, we don't need the data pointer anymore since an derived task can add whatever members it wants to.

```
class Task
{
public:
    Task()
    {
        Empty.store(true);
        Data = nullptr;
    }
    std::mutex Access;
    std::atomic<bool> Empty;
    virtual void Work() = 0;
};
```

Just to make it more clear, here are two short examples of how I would start jobs from within the main thread. Let's start with the first one.

```
int number;

Task<int> *example = new Task<int>();
example.Data = &number;
example.Empty.store(false);
example.Run = [](int* number){
    *number = 42;
});

Queue.push_back(example);
```

And for the second approach.

```
class Example : public Task
{
public:
    Example(int *number)
    {
        this->number = number;
    }
    void Work()
    {
        *number = 42;
    }
    int number;
};

int number;

Example *example = new Example(&number);    
example.Empty.store(false);

Queue.push_back(example);
```

What are the difference in performance and flexibility of those two approaches?

Comment: Why don't you use Intel's TBB (which is free, C++, task-based parallelism for multithreading)? Btw, TBB uses the inheritance model, when the user must override the `tbb::task::execute()` function, which can use several members of `tbb::task`, for example to spawn further sub-tasks.

Comment: Since you appear to be using C++ 11 why not use a [`packaged_task`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/packaged_task/)?

Comment: What is the reason for templating the Task class? This is a clear case of 'is a' relationship between Example and Task

Comment: @Mgetz Could you elaborate on how to use `std::packaged_task` to get the described behavior, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example lets you use any arbitrary thread function without having to define an entirely new class for it. The main issue, however, is that you must allocate memory for the user data to pass it to the thread function. So even for a task that should just take an integer, you still have to pass a pointer to it.

The second approach, however, lets you add any number of members of any size to the task, and also gives you private access to the actual `Task` instance, which may be beneficial later on. Furthermore, because it is not templated, it's easier to maintain a list of `Task` instances.

As far as performance is concerned, they're pretty much the same, since virtual functions are just implemented as function pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The inheritance approach is clearly the most idiomatic and efficient way. The base class `Task` implements all the work-sharing and queuing etc, while the user only has to override the pure virtual member `Work()`. This allows the implementation of the task spreading (queuing etc) to be implmented independent of the actual work of the task.

The virtual table look-up (call `Task::Work()`) is the least of your worries when it comes to the performance of multi-threaded applications. The real issue are race conditions on the work queues and efficient spreading of sub-tasks ... See also Intel's tbb (http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/).